# How to force Capacitor App to reload programmatically

Tags: javascript, angular, capacitor

I would like to be able to restart my app programmatically. It should run on all platforms (electron, ios, android, web). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
document.location.href = 'index.html';
```

Comment: The problem with your solution, is that native event listeners will not be cleaned up, so you will get a memory leak with that.